# Boundaries of holes in a toast burn faster?

Tags: thermodynamics

Based on observations of my own toaster, it seems to me that if a piece of bread contains a hole, then the part of the bread surrounding the hole heats up more quickly then the majority of the rest of the bread. Can anyone confirm a similar observation and/or explain this?

Comment: I suspect that this is related to that a 90 degree edge around the bread hole has less volume of bread around itself to dissipate the incident radiative heat than a point on a flat bread-piece..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume the bread is consisted of similar tiny tiny pieces, each having the same mass and surface. Also, assume there is a uniform heat flux everywhere.

The pieces close to a hole or at the sides of the bread have a larger portion of their surface exposed to heat, than a piece that is surrounded by other pieces, therefore they absorb heat at a faster rate.

This makes their temperature rise faster, and they start burning before the rest of the bread does.